# loop was not vectorized because it contains a reference to a non-vector intrinsic

Tags: fortran, vectorization

I am coding a large Fortran program where performance is extremely crucial. I'm using module to store common parameters and variables. But the problem is where ever there's a module variable is used for some kind of array operation the compiler doesn't vectorize it. Lets take this as an example,

```
module name
    integer :: p    
end module name


program name1
    use name
    real(kind=8) :: x(10,10), y(10)
    integer :: i,j 
    p=9
    do i=1,10
        do j =1,10
            x(i,j) = i+j
        enddo
    enddo

    y = x(:,p)*x(:,p-1)
    print *, y
end program name1
```

Now when I compile it on `Cray (XC50)` with `ftn -eD file.f90`, the produced `.lst` file shows,

```
   9.    program name1
   10.        ! implicit none
   11.        use name
   12.        real(kind=8) :: x(10,10), y(10)
   13.        integer :: i,j
   14.        do i=1,10
   15.            do j =1,10
   16.                x(i,j) = i+j
   17.            enddo
   18.        enddo
   19.
   20.        y = x(:,p)*x(:,p-1)
ftn-6263 ftn: VECTOR NAME1, File = test.f90, Line = 20
  A loop starting at line 20 was not vectorized because it contains a reference to a non-vector intrinsic on line 20.

   21.        print *, y
   22.    end program name1
   23.
   24.
```

I always thought that doing array operation with `:` will be easier for the compiler to vectorize it. But if using module variable is bad for vectorization then is it also bad to use module when performance is critical? Am I confusing something here? How to improve the performance for these cases?

Comment: Can you force the compiler vectorize your operation by doing something like `y = dot_product(x(:,p-1),x(:,p))` ?

Comment: Okay now it shows `A loop starting at line 20 was partially vectorized.`

Comment: If your CPU has 4/8-lane SIMD capability for 64-bit floating point operations, an array with size 10 cannot be fully vectorized, so the compiler will likely run ranges [1:4] and [5:8] as SIMD, while elements 9 and 10 will be serial code. Also: I noticed you're not computing a dot product, so my former comment is not a valid replacement of your original code. An option would be to try `forall(i=1:10) y(i) = x(i,p)*x(i,p-1)` or, similarly, with a `do concurrent`

Comment: The above one was a very simple example. Actual ones may be much larger and complicated and I have thousands of such operation. So, what would you finally suggest to follow in such cases? (May be you can drop a answer here.)

Comment: It may have decided not to vectorise because the vector length is so short. What happens if you make it longer? What happens if the length is passed as an argument to a subprogram?

Comment: And note forall is now deprecated, so best avoided